# Artifacts in TikZ picture when using scale option

Tags: tikz-pgf, texlive

When compiling the example code below with pdflatex Version 3.1415926-2.4-1.40.13 (TeX Live 2012/W32TeX), I observe an artifact (horizontal line starting from the start point of the objects) in the scaled-down version of the tikzpicture. Any help on how to fix this would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

  \def\myFig{
      +(0,0) to [out=90,in=270]  +(0,1)
             to [out=90,in=270]  +(1,3)
             to [out=90,in=270]  +(-0.3,1)
             to [out=90,in=180]  +(1,1)
             to [out=0,in=90]    +(1,-1)
             to [out=270,in=90]  +(-0.3,-1)
             to [out=270,in=90]  +(1,-3)
             to [out=270,in=90]  +(0,-1)
             to [out=270,in=0]   +(-0.3,-0.3)
             to [out=180,in=0]   +(-2.8,0)
             to [out=180,in=270] +(-0.3,0.3)
             -- cycle;
  } 

  scale=1: figure looks ok

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
    \draw[step=1,lightgray] (-5,0) grid (5,10);
    \draw[gray,thick,fill=gray!10] (-4.2,2.5) \myFig;
    \draw[thick,fill=gray!40,rotate=-18] (0.7,1.1) \myFig;
  \end{tikzpicture}

  \vspace{1cm}
  scale smaller than 1:  figure contains additional lines

  \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.4]
    \draw[step=1,lightgray] (-5,0) grid (5,10);
    \draw[gray,thick,fill=gray!10] (-4.2,2.5) \myFig;
    \draw[thick,fill=gray!40,rotate=-18] (0.7,1.1) \myFig;
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Which TikZ version are you using?

Comment: Could you please provide pictures, I get the correct image (perfectly scaled, and nothing more).

Comment: No additional lines here (TeX Live2012 + PGF version 2.10). What version of PGF/TikZ do you use?

Comment: I can reproduce this. MiKTeX 2.9, TikZ CVS. It depends on the PDF viewer, Adobe Acrobat does not show additional lines, Sumatra PDF does. Chromes integrated viewer shows no additional lines.

Comment: I'm not allowed to add images (reputation too low yet). Maybe as a link in the comments?: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aadcac3se58j4hm/tikz_issue.jpg

@GonzaloMedina: I'm using Tex Live 2012 as of today (2013-03-18) and the TikZ version that came with it.

Comment: @Alexander: confirmed. I see the artifacts with SumatraPDF. Acrobat doesn't show them. So it seems to be a viewer bug? Scary.

Comment: @Mathias indeed it seems, you should supply the pdf to SumatraPDF (probably compile it with `\pdfcompresslevel=0` so that the developers there can examine the object stream). I guess we can close it as _off topic_ as it is viewer dependent (I cannot reproduce this with xpdf nor evince)

Comment: @zeroth: ok, I'll do that. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Mathias could you provide a link to the PDF, just to rule out any discrepancies between versions, etc.?

Comment: Sure, here's the link: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1280560/document.pdf

Comment: @Mathias great, thanks. I still have no errors showing the PDF. So please go forward with SumatraPDF contact. :)